# Testing and Development Workflow of a complex widget meant to run in a customers website

Tags: javascript, widget

I want to develop a service that is based on a widget that is running on my customers' websites. Think of UserVoice or Intercom, but mine would potentially also include authentication of their customer to my service and payment handling.

How would you set up testing of such a complex widget? What development workflow would you recommend?

Comment: Could the downvoters please explain why you don't like the question or how it could be improved?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an end to end (E2E)test using [webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io/) and mocha. you will have to create a few programs for that:

- Mock client server - serves a page with the widget.
- Widget client - Served from the client server
- Widget Server - where widget clients connect.
- Selenium server - which opens a browser and will initiate the test.

The flow of your End2End test will be as following

- start all servers: selenium, client, widget server.
- test will run selenium client and connect to selenium server.
- selenium server will start a browser and will connect to client server.
- the browser will get the client software and will wait for widget
- widget code will try to connect to widget service.
- widget code will change something in the ui on successful connections.
- your test will instruct selenium to look for that change.

Eventually if you follow some kind of TDD and personal sanity I would suggest to keep a simple E2E for your basic testing and move as much logic to integration/unit test level. Here is some code to get a simple notion of the actual test after all servers are up:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = { desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' } };
var client = webdriverio.remote(options);

client
    .init()
    .url('[ClientServerURL]')
    .pause(100000)
    .getSomething(/*...*/)
    .then(()=>{
        //expect results.
     })
    .end();
```